# Material-table example doesn't work as intended

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui, material-table

In Material-UI's website Table page, there's one specific table that I was interested in using for a project, labeled material-table (https://material-ui.com/components/tables/#material-table). It's got a search bar, a button for adding new rows, and the possibility of editing or deleting existing rows, also through buttons. In the site, everything works perfectly, but the source code provided doesn't, and I'm not sure why.

```
import React from 'react';
import MaterialTable from 'material-table';

export default function MaterialTableDemo() {
  const [state, setState] = React.useState({
    columns: [
      { title: 'Name', field: 'name' },
      { title: 'Surname', field: 'surname' },
      { title: 'Birth Year', field: 'birthYear', type: 'numeric' },
      {
        title: 'Birth Place',
        field: 'birthCity',
        lookup: { 34: 'İstanbul', 63: 'Şanlıurfa' },
      },
    ],
    data: [
      { name: 'Mehmet', surname: 'Baran', birthYear: 1987, birthCity: 63 },
      {
        name: 'Zerya Betül',
        surname: 'Baran',
        birthYear: 2017,
        birthCity: 34,
      },
    ],
  });

  return (
    <MaterialTable
      title="Editable Example"
      columns={state.columns}
      data={state.data}
      editable={{
        onRowAdd: newData =>
          new Promise(resolve => {
            setTimeout(() => {
              resolve();
              setState(prevState => {
                const data = [...prevState.data];
                data.push(newData);
                return { ...prevState, data };
              });
            }, 600);
          }),
        onRowUpdate: (newData, oldData) =>
          new Promise(resolve => {
            setTimeout(() => {
              resolve();
              if (oldData) {
                setState(prevState => {
                  const data = [...prevState.data];
                  data[data.indexOf(oldData)] = newData;
                  return { ...prevState, data };
                });
              }
            }, 600);
          }),
        onRowDelete: oldData =>
          new Promise(resolve => {
            setTimeout(() => {
              resolve();
              setState(prevState => {
                const data = [...prevState.data];
                data.splice(data.indexOf(oldData), 1);
                return { ...prevState, data };
              });
            }, 600);
          }),
      }}
    />
  );
}
```

The code above is the one shown on the site. When I try to use it, however, while the **Edit** button allows me to change the fields of the selected row, the changes are not saved when I use the Save button.

Also, the **Delete** one seems to always delete the last row of the table, even if it wasn't the one I chose to delete. Adding new rows, however, seems to work normally.

How can I fix this?

Comment: You might want to console log the value of `data.indexOf(oldData)` because I suspect it isn't working like you intend. You may want to do something like `data.findIndex(e => e.name === oldData.name)`.

Comment: Same problem here! Have you found a way?

Answer (score 0):

```
const data = [...prevState.data];
data[data.indexOf(oldData)] = newData;
```

I changed it into:

```
const foundIndex = oldData.findIndex(x => x.name === newData.name)
data[foundIndex] = newData
return data
```

Answer (score 0):

It isn't pretty and I don't get all the setTimeouts, but here are working edit and delete on the current `demo.js` in the `material-table` on GitHub as of today (the reason I found this question in the first place, because edit and delete don't work on that code either). NOTE: This is scoped to `this` and does not use `prevState` style usage of `setState`, but leaving this here as a working solution for `demo.js` code.

```
  onRowUpdate: (newData, oldData) =>
    new Promise(resolve => {
      setTimeout(() => {
        resolve();
        if (oldData) {
          const data = [...this.state.data];
          const foundIndex = data.findIndex(x => x.name === newData.name)
          data[foundIndex] = newData
          this.setState({...this.state, data});
        }
      }, 600);
    }),
  onRowDelete: (oldData) =>
    new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      setTimeout(() => {
        resolve();
        const data = [...this.state.data];
        const foundIndex = data.findIndex(x => x.name === oldData.name)
        data.splice(foundIndex, 1);
        this.setState({...this.state, data});
      }, 1000);
    }),
```